# Django REST framework RetrieveAPIView gets empty "id" parameter and returns 404 error

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I use Django 1.11 + Django REST Framework. I'm trying to get detailed data about distinct record using generic RetrieveAPIView from Django REST Framework and server returns "HTTP 404 Not Found" result, i.e. no data.

***models.py*** file:

```
class TestPage( models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(  size = 120)
    counter = models.IntegerField( default = 0)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'' + self.title
```

***serializers.py*** file:

```
class TestPageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'counter',)
        model = models.TestPage
```

***urls.py*** file:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url( r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url( r'^api/', include( 'rest_framework.urls')), 
    url( r'^api/', include( 'testpages.urls')),  
    ]
```

***testpages/urls.py*** file:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url( r'^$', views.TestPageList.as_view()),
    url( r'^(?P<id>)\d+/$', views.TestPageDetail.as_view()),  
    ]
```

*and at last **views.py** file:*

```
class TestPageList(generics.ListAPIView):
    lookup_field = 'id'
    queryset = TestPage.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TestPageSerializer

class TestPageDetail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    lookup_field = 'id'
    queryset = TestPage.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TestPageSerializer
    # def get_object( self):
    #    print self.kwargs
```

If I request "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/" for all records in the list, server returns all records. But if I want to get record by id using "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/1/" for example, I get the empty result like in the photo below.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

If I uncomment get_object()-function in last 2 lines, I can see {'id': u''} in terminal  i.e. server gets empty parameter 'id'.

What wrong with this code?

Comment: You can combine both of them into a single `ViewSet`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is your regular expression matching for `id`, you're putting `\d+` outside of the matching group when it's actually what you want to match:

```
url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.TestPageDetail.as_view())
```

By the way, to be good REST citizen, you shouldn't add the `/` at the end of a URL for a specific object.

Note: As mentioned by JPG, adding a name for the resource you're fetching (plural) would be proper RESTful:

```
url(r'^pages/(?P<id>\d+)$', views.TestPageDetail.as_view())
```

This way, you fetch page nr. 1 at `/api/pages/1`

Comment: I missed that *regex part*. +1 for that :)

Comment: Thank you very much, dirkgroten! ِActually I misplaced ')'.

Answer (score 1):

The original problem was the ***closing parathesis*** (the regex expression), you were misplaced that.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.TestPageList.as_view()),
    url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.TestPageDetail.as_view()),
                    ^^^ here
]
```

Apart from that, You should change the urls patterns to a ***sensible*** form, as

```
#testpages/urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^test/$', views.TestPageList.as_view()),
    url(r'^test/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.TestPageDetail.as_view()),
]
```

then the ***list-api*** will be available on **`/api/test/`** endpoint 
and the ***detail-api*** will be available on **`/api/test/{id}/`**

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I don't think the problem is in this urls-file. The thing is the first line in urls.py (for TestPageList.as_view()) works nice and returns list of records. The problem only with the second one. 'id' == '' in result. Can be problem in Django version (I use 1.11,  not 2.x)?